# In the source files of an Eclipse plug-in, why are a lot of variables prefixed with "f"?

Tags: java, eclipse, syntax, naming-conventions

I'm going through the source code for Eclipse plugins (right now I'm exploring the class [`TextMergeView`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/compare/contentmergeviewer/TextMergeViewer.html)) and I notice ALOT of variables are given the starting letter `f`.

I know that we often give interfaces the prefix `I` to make it easy to identify them as interfaces upon first glance. But what could `f` mean?

Here's a fragment:

```
......
private int fInheritedDirection;    // inherited direction
    private int fTextDirection;         // requested direction for embedded SourceViewer

    private ActionContributionItem fIgnoreAncestorItem;
    private boolean fHighlightRanges;

    private boolean fShowPseudoConflicts= false;

    private boolean fUseSplines= true;
    private boolean fUseSingleLine= true;
    private boolean fUseResolveUI= true;
    private boolean fHighlightTokenChanges = false;

    private String fSymbolicFontName;

    private ActionContributionItem fNextDiff;   // goto next difference
    private ActionContributionItem fPreviousDiff;   // goto previous difference
    private ActionContributionItem fCopyDiffLeftToRightItem;
    private ActionContributionItem fCopyDiffRightToLeftItem;

    private CompareHandlerService fHandlerService;

    private boolean fSynchronizedScrolling= true;
...
```

Why do these variable start with `f`? What does the f mean as a prefix?

Answer (score 6):

It almost certainly means "field" but it goes *explicitly* against the [Eclipse coding conventions](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Recommenders/CodingConventions#Private_class_variables_must_not_have_any_field_prefix_or_suffix.):

> Private class variables must not have any field prefix or suffix.
>
> ```
> class Person
> {
>     private String name; // NOT private String _name;
>     // NOT private String fName;
>     // NOT private String name_;
>     ...
> }
> ```

I suspect this code is older than the coding conventions...

Comment: This code was written for a plugin for Eclipse 3.3. (Btw, it's an honor to have you answer my question :)